# Replacing Python requests with tornado HTTPclient doesn't work with basic auth

Tags: python, http, tornado

There is a simple code on Python using requests module to make 1 get request with basic authorization. It works.
Then raised a need to rewrite this code to use tornado HTTP client. It doesn't work. Server returns 500 code. I tried HTTP client and AsyncHTTP client, both doesn't work.
Also I have other request, it need authorization token instead of basic auth and it works with Tornado AsyncHTTP client
Here is working and non-working examples with logs. Could you please help to find the reason of error? HTTP logs are quite similar, I don't see any substant difference. I tried to check non-working example without headers Connection and Content-Length, nothing changed.
I deleted from examples password, user name and host name, but I ckecked a lot of times they are identical in working and non-working examples.

Working example:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
url = "http://myhost:81/oapi/GetDate/4rnm"
details_ = requests.get(url, headers={'x-app-id': "kav_test"}, timeout=30, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("user", "login"))
```

Log from working example:

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): myhost
send: b'GET /oapi/GetDate/4rnm HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: myhost:81\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.18.4\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nx-app-id: kav_test\r\nAuthorization: Basic foo==\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:myhost:81 "GET /oapi/GetDate/4rnm HTTP/1.1" 200 None
header: Transfer-Encoding header: Content-Type header: Server header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin header: Access-Control-Allow-Headers header: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header: Access-Control-Allow-Methods header: Access-Control-Max-Age header: Set-Cookie header: Date {"date":"2021-01-01","hasErrors":false,"errors":[]}
```

non-working example:

```
from tornado import httpclient, ioloop
    http_client_ = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
...
    url = "http://myhost:81/oapi/GetDate/4rnm"
    response = await http_client_.fetch(url, method='GET', auth_username="user", auth_password="login", headers={'x-app-id': "test", "Connection": "keep-alive", "Content-Length": "0"}
```

Log from non-working example:
There is an error Host not found in the end, but I don't understand why, because on the top of log there is a connection with the the host.

```
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: SelectSelector
DEBUG:tornado.curl_httpclient:GET myhost:81/oapi/GetDate/4rnm (username: 'foo')
DEBUG:tornado.curl_httpclient:Trying myip...
DEBUG:tornado.curl_httpclient:TCP_NODELAY set
DEBUG:tornado.curl_httpclient:Connected to myhost (myip) port 81 (#0)
DEBUG:tornado.curl_httpclient:Server auth using Basic with user 'foo'
DEBUG:tornado.curl_httpclient:> GET /oapi/GetDate/4rnm HTTP/1.1
DEBUG:tornado.curl_httpclient:> Host: myhost:81
DEBUG:tornado.curl_httpclient:> Authorization: Basic foo==
DEBUG:tornado.curl_httpclient:> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; pycurl)
DEBUG:tornado.curl_httpclient:> Accept: */*
DEBUG:tornado.curl_httpclient:> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
DEBUG:tornado.curl_httpclient:> X-App-Id: kav_test
DEBUG:tornado.curl_httpclient:> Connection: keep-alive
DEBUG:tornado.curl_httpclient:> Content-Length: 0
DEBUG:tornado.curl_httpclient:>
Traceback (most recent call last):
DEBUG:tornado.curl_httpclient:< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
DEBUG:tornado.curl_httpclient:< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
DEBUG:tornado.curl_httpclient:< Content-Type: application/json
tornado.httpclient.HTTPClientError: HTTP 500: Internal Server Error
DEBUG:tornado.curl_httpclient:< X-Error-Msg: 
Host (myhost:81) not found.
(x-local://wtv/wtv_tools_web.xml,   line 5689)
(x-local://wtv/wtv_tools_web.xml,   line 6149)
(user_init(),  wt\web\openapi.html,   line 976)
(Authorize(),  wt\web\openapi.html,   line 896)
(wt\web\openapi.html,   line 1079)
```

Comment: The logs don't agree with the code snippets. The tornado code has `auth_username="user"` and `x-app-id: test` but the log has username `foo` and `X-App-Id: kav_test`. Is this exactly the code you ran? What server is running on `myhost:81`?

Comment: Also you should not manually send Connection or Content-Length headers - those are for the HTTP client to manage and trying to send them yourself can break things (seems unlikely to be the problem here, though).

Comment: Yes, the code was exactly the same. I preferred not to post real username and x-app-id, but missed. In fact requests contained the same credentials. Also I tried with and without Content-Length and Connection headers, and result was the same